# Organize the contents of a csv table by changing the order of rows and columns

Tags: algorithm, csv, machine-learning

Having a csv file, is there any known approach to change the order of columns and rows to get a visual consistency.
My point is to achieve something like in the following example (**It is just an example**. Please assume that the table can be much bigger):

```
// input                    
    c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
r1  ✓   ✓       ✓   
r2  ✓   ✓       ✓   
r3                  
r4  ✓   ✓       ✓   ✓
r5  ✓               
                    
// output (desired state)                   
    c3  c5  c2  c4  c1
r4      ✓   ✓   ✓   ✓
r2          ✓   ✓   ✓
r1          ✓   ✓   ✓
r5                   ✓
r3
```

What comes to mind is to use a metric where I would assign a given setup:

- a positive point for every '**✓**' adjacent to a '**✓**'
- a negative point for every '**✓**' adjacent to an **empty field**.

Each unique state would have a corresponding metric value. The higher it is, the more desirable state it represents.

Starting from this point, I could take a primitive *n* iteration approach. Where each iteration would randomly shift rows and columns and then I would choose the state from iteration which would have the highest value of the calculated metric.

The second approach that comes to mind is the use of some machine learning algorithm because the very fact of the existence of the metric that I mentioned above seems to suggest the use of some loss function.

However, I am not sure what specific learning mechanism I should choose in such case and would be very grateful for any suggestions.

(just to clarify: The fact that ticks are grouped towards top right bottom is not the goal in itself (grouping them towards any other corner would be equally desirable). The goal is to reduce metric described earlier)

Comment: I'd start by reducing the problem by temporarily setting aside rows and columns that don't contribute to the core problem. So empty rows and columns can be set aside. They will be at the bottom and left respectively in the final solution. And only one copy of duplicate rows and columns needs to be considered. So row 2 and be set aside because it's a duplicate of row 1, and column 4 can be set aside because it's a duplicate of column 2. Hence, the problem is reduced from 5x5 to 3x3 with rows 1,4,5 and columns 1,2,5.

Comment: Is there a reason to use machine learning?  Seems easy enough to sort columns by most used to least.  And afterwards to order rows by values by count of checkmarks first, and placement of the first checkmark second.

Comment: I agree with btilly that the example makes the problem seem easier than it is. You can make the problem harder (without changing the size of the matrix) by making sure that my first comment has no effect. So a better example might be `11010, 10110, 00001, 11011, 10000` where one of the eight solutions (according to the metric as I understand it) is `00001, 01111, 01110, 11100, 01000`

Comment: An example where the metric doesn't work very well is `11010, 10110, 00001, 11111, 10000`. A typical solution with the best score is `00001, 01000, 11100, 11111, 01110`. A better solution (imo), but a lower score, can be produced by rearranging the rows to `00001, 11111, 01110, 11100, 01000`. That demonstrates one of the limitations of metric-based solutions: sometimes the metric has unintended consequences. In this case, the metric puts an isolated 1 in the corner of the matrix, which limits its negative effect without furthering the actual goal of grouping all the 1s together.

Comment: @btilly The table that I provided in the question is just an example. If I am correct for this example we would have just 5! * 5! possible states so probably it wouldn't be a problem to generate all of them and find a state with the best metric value. But if we had table that is much bigger then I think it could be problematic to do so. My assumption is that correct colution does not generate all of the states upfront and picks state which has the greates metric value but rather generates state that is 'good enough'.

Comment: @bridgemnc And my point is that a simple heuristic can do pretty well, much more efficiently than machine learning.